# In Clojurescript, how do I pass a collection's elements as arguments to a variable arity Javascript function?

Tags: interop, clojurescript

This writes to console the way I would expect:

```
(.log js/console "hi" "there")
```

The output is

```
hi there
```

This, however, just writes a big mess to the console:

```
(defn log-it [& args] (.log js/console args))
(log-it "hello" "there")
```

The output is:

```
c…s.c…e.IndexedSeq {arr: Array[2], i: 0, meta: null, cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$: 166592766, cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition1$: 8192}
```

This also does NOT work:

```
(apply .log js/console ["hi" "there"])
```

Is there a way to pass the vector's elements into the .log function?
Do I have to write a macro to concat the vector on to `'(.log js/console)`?

Comment: what version of clojurescript.  I'm running planck 1.17 with clojurescript 1.9 and your `log-it` function seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to log the value of `args` (which is a Clojure IndexedSeq) rather than passing the values in the seq as individual arguments. In this case you need to use `apply` (or convert that sequence to a native data structure).

The reason your other example doesn't work should become clear if you look at [the signature for `apply`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply).

```
(apply f args)
```

It expects the first argument to be the function you want to invoke, but here, the first argument is `.log`.

```
(apply .log js/console ["hi" "there"])
```

Remember that `.log js/console` is the syntax for invoking the `log` method on `console`. Instead, we want to get a reference to the `console.log` function.

```
(apply (.-log js/console) args)
```

We're using `.-log` to read the `.log` property, rather than call it as a method. Then we pass that along with our `args` sequence.

So instead, you can define the original function as:

```
(defn log-it
  [& args]
  (apply (.-log js/console) args))
```

Or if you want to get a little bit smarter.

```
(def log-it (partial (.-log js/console)))
```

Comment: great answer. last code snippet is missing one closing paren